# Let's remove the socializing tag

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, burninate-request

The [socializing](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socializing) tag seems to be used for any question involving interpersonal skills, and doesn't seem to have any sort of specific meaning. Questions with the tag range from questions about [the link between self-esteem and spending time on the internet](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/impact-of-the-internet-on-peoples-high-self-opinion), to [questions about how to tell friends that it's your birthday](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/its-my-birthday-how-do-i-tell-people-who-dont-know-who-might-want-to-know-w). The inconsistent nature of the tag makes me question the tags usefulness.

It seems to me that people are using the tag for any question involving social interaction, which is potentially every question on the site. The tag wiki contributes to this (" For questions about socially mixing up with others, or make someone behave in a way that is acceptable to their society."), but nobody actually reads the tag wikis before deciding whether to use a tag. Something about the name "socializing" isn't working here.

Could we remove this tag, and replace it with more specific tags?

Answer (score -1):

I just went to the non-meta questions section and clicked on 20 questions in a row - and none had the socializing tag. So overuse doesn't seem to be a problem.

As for the term itself, "socializing" doesn't tend to refer to all interaction. For instance, I don't think that there are many people who would call a job interview "socializing." It may be that some people use the tag in a way that seems wrong, but I would call that a reason to correct them, not to get rid of the tag.